# How to add web folders for web flutter from mobile applications that have been created

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I have structure folder like this:

[image]

I want to display my mobile application on the web using Flutter.
So, I want to add folder web for Flutter web, I have done several ways, but I did not get the solution.
[image]

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Switch to the Flutter master channel and upgrade to the latest release***

```
Flutter channel master
Flutter upgrade
```

**Enable the Flutter Web you haven’t already**

```
flutter config --enable-web
```

**Check you you got Chrome in your attached devices list**

```
fluter devices
```

**Create the Web platform folder in the Flutter App**

```
flutter create .
```

**Run on Web**

```
flutter run -d Chrome
```

Flutter official resources to start with Flutter web:
[https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web][1]

Update on 3rd May

Flutter Web is by default enabled in the latest version of Flutter you don’t need to enable the Flutter web and use the Flutter master channel either.

Comment: after I made the master channel, there was an error, fatal: remote origin already exists. However, the channel master is not installed in the flutter yet

Comment: Is it possible to create only the "web" folder on a project that already exists and enable flutter web?

Comment: Just found a solution, I had to open terminal inside the project's folder is and run "flutter create nameoftheproject"

Comment: ah, I didn't notice there is a `.` after `Flutter create`. Took me a while to find it from somewhere else. Please quote the command for more clarification. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the command
flutter create --platforms web .

from https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/building